# How to create an empty array of arrays in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to initialize an empty array which itself contains 5 empty arrays. But matlab seems to just create a simple empty array variable instead. Following are the two syntaxes I have tried. Any ideas if it is possible in matlab?

```
bins = [ []; []; []; []; []  ];

bins = repmat([], 5, 1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB only has matrices, i.e. (potentially multidimensional) arrays of numerical types (or characters or logical values). To group other structures in one variable, try a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/cell.html), e.g.

```
bins = { []; []; []; []; []  };
```

You then have to access elements of the outer array with curly brackets, e.g. `bins{2}` instead of `bins(2)`.

Answer (score 4):

`deal` is a good function for such an assignment:

```
[bins{1:5}] = deal([]);
```

This creates a cell array `bins`, where each element `bins{i}` contains an empty array.

Comment: How about fully pre-allocating a 2D array? In that case, the `[]` inside the `deal` would itself need to be m empty spaces. Initializing it with empty members instead of using `zeros` is better if there is a chance what is going into the array would itself have a value of 0 (otherwise you can't distinguish between a zero in the data or an error stopping you from assigning to that position).

Answer (score 0):

Another trick to initialize this:

```
>> bins = {}      %# just to make sure `bins` wasn't used before
>> bins{5} = []
bins = 
    []    []    []    []    []
```